# OpenJDK patched with font fixes mess up google chrome fonts

Tags: java, google-chrome, fonts, openjdk

I've installed the patched OpenJDK in order to get proper font rendering in WebStorm 8. It works fine but i realized chrome has some font rendering problems since then. I only see this in chrome so far, Firefox has no problems, either any other applications on the system.

I followed this gist: gist.github.com/leemour/5620265.

A screenshots about the problem: ( look at the fontawesome font rendering, and the devtools window )

[image]

**EDIT:** the problem solved, there is a gist that summarizes the steps: https://gist.github.com/TheSpiritMolecule/6580548808a2828b0cb1

Comment: Try to remove infinality: `sudo apt-get purge fontconfig-infinality`. I have a similar setup (just haven't installed that) and fonts are correctly rendered.

Comment: for me it messed it up :D even thought chrome was fixed. [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/8LcZ2De.png?1)  ***EDIT:*** after i reinstalled the module to fix up web storm, chrome was fixed somehow... now both works fine without any bugs. Chrome and webstorm as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove infinality. It is not strictly needed:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge fontconfig-infinality
```

BTW the weird rendering you see in your second screenshot (fonts pixelated and "bolded") are related to WebStorm not getting the Java parameters:

```
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
-Dsun.java2d.xrender=true
-Dswing.aatext=true
```

This will happen to other Java programs unless you add those parameters to each Java launcher. An easier way to do that is just creating a file (`/etc/profile.d/java_opts.sh`) with the following content:

```
export _JAVA_OPTS="-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd -Dsun.java2d.xrender=true -Dswing.aatext=true"
```

and make it executable:

```
$ sudo chmod +x /etc/profile.d/java_opts.sh
```

Note that those settings will only be loaded after you logout/login.

Also you can check if an app is using those settings starting it from a terminal. You should see a line starting with `Picked up _JAVA_OPTS`

Comment: I actually has these two lines on the end of `webstorm.vmoptions`. I also created that file and relogged to ubuntu. Unfortunately it is still the same. haha :D

Comment: @AttilaEgyed Try to add also `-Dsun.java2d.xrender=true`

Comment: This one solved the problem! Also included it to the startup .sh file. Thank you :)